# Weight diagram for $(2 \, 1)$ representation of $SU(3)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Decided to practice my knowledge of representation theory by constructing the weight diagram for the representation $(2 \, 1)$ of $SU(3)$. This is apparently the $\mathbf{15}$, but when I use what I recall of the method to construct the weights at lower levels using the simple roots, I arrive at dimension 11.

Here's the diagram, where the simple roots are $\alpha_1 = (2 ~ \bar{1})$ and $\alpha_2 = (\bar{1} ~ 2)$, and an overbar denotes a minus sign:

$
\large\qquad {(2~1)} \\
\quad {\alpha_1} \nearrow \quad \nwarrow \alpha_2\\
\large(0 ~ 2)\quad\quad(3~\bar{1})\\
~\alpha_1\uparrow \qquad \quad \uparrow\alpha_1 \\
\large(\bar{2} ~ 3) \quad\quad (1~0)\\
\quad \alpha_2 \nwarrow \quad\nearrow \alpha_1 \\
\large~~~\qquad(\bar{1} ~ 1)\\
\quad\alpha_1\nearrow \quad \nwarrow \alpha_2\\
\large(\bar{3} ~~ 2) \quad \quad (0 ~ \bar{1})\\
~\alpha_2\uparrow \qquad \uparrow  \alpha_2\\
\large(\bar{2} ~ 0)\quad \quad (1 ~ \bar{3})\\
\quad \alpha_2\nwarrow \quad\nearrow\alpha_1 \\
\large~~~~\quad(\bar1 ~ \bar{2})
$

I'm able to correctly get the $\mathbf{10}$ and $\mathbf{8}$ using what I recall.

Comment: Are you sure those weights all occur with multiplicity $1$? (I did not do any calclations myself, but that would be an easy place to get an error). Certainly the irrep with highest weight $(2,1)$ has dimension $15$ by Weyl's dimension formula (assuming you are writing these in terms of the fundamental weights).

Comment: I did think that, and indeed some of these weights can be reached by two different arrows - (1 0), (-1 1), (0 -1), (-2 0), (-1 -2) - but they aren't degenerate in the way that the weight (0 0) is in the adjoint of SU(3).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the weights are repeated.  The weights $(0,1),(-1,1),(0,-1)$ are repeated twice.  Somehow you're also missing the weight $(2,-2)$, which occurs once.  This weight would "sit" below $(-1,1)$ but above $(-3,2)$ and $(0,-1)$. With these adjustments you now sum up to $15$.

I'm pretty sure I have it right as I have a code which uses the Freudenthal formula to generate weights and their multiplicities, and I get *exactly* the same tower as you get (in reverse order as I start from the highest weight) except for the additional $(2,-2)$ weight located as described above.  My code also produces the weight multiplicities using the same formula.